# PHP understanding a small snippet code for extracting checkbox values

Tags: php

I have a snippet of PHP code, it works but I was curious to know why.

```
Green: <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="green" />
Black: <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="black" />
White: <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="white" />
Blue:  <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue"  />
Red:   <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red"   />
```

then here is what I don't get for this PHP code below, how is $colors an array, I thought you have to at least have $colors[] = $_POST['color'].

```
if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
  $colors = $_POST['color'];
}
echo $colors[0];
```

Thanks for helping me better understand this.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly add `[]` in PHP. Notice that you don't even need to define the type! This is PHP :)

`$_POST['color']` is an array, so `$colors` will also be!

Read: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

## Edit

In PHP, if you write `$colors[] = $var`, you are actually adding `$var` to the end of that array. If the array is empty, `$colors[0] == $var`.

```
$colors = $_POST['color']; // $colors receives the array
$colors[] = $_POST['color']; // $colors[0] receives the array, if $colors was empty
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: AFAIK, you have to specify `[]` for it to be an array.

Comment: PHP doesn't require that (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). However, in the HTML, `name="var[]` is required so that those elements can be identified as an array.

Comment: I was talking about the `HTML`.

Comment: Thought you were talking about `PHP` :) I added additional info, so nobody gets confused.

Comment: Understood, I thought you mean't `HTML` in the above post. :P

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, every element with [] in its name is gonna be treated as an array.

Useful in cases like:

```
Choose your interests<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Fashion'> Fashion
<input type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Cars'> Cars
<input type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Health'> Health
<input type='checkbox' name='interests[]' value='Programming'> Programming
```

Now you will acces them as an array in php:

```
$_POST['interests'][0] //-> Fashion
```